# App re-install required for push notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, upgrade

I have some really weird behavior on iOS.
I have an app that used to use parse push notifications.
Since parse shut down on Jan 30th, I switched to back4app.
I was testing sending push notifications - my app was subscribed to a test channel and I was sending pushes to the channel.
I was using two phones.

At around 5pm, I was getting notifications correctly on both phones (phone1 running version A and phone2 running version B).
At around 6pm, I got notifications on only one phone (version B) and not the other (version A).
I logged into the phone, checked the app store, and updated version A -> B. So now both phones have version B.

Still phone1 had no notifications but phone2 did.
I then uninstalled the app on phone2 and reinstalled.
Now, at around 8pm, both phones get notifications.

It is really concerning that notifications stopped showing up on phone 1 and didn't show up even after the upgrade, and required re-install to work.
I register `registerForRemoteNotifications` in a plugin init call, and I confirmed from the logs that I successfully registered, and saved the token and was on the right channel.

`Feb 13 19:23:30 ucb-sdb-iphone-1 emission[674] <Warning>: Successfully registered remote push notifications for token <c2a21dac d3e1678c 8fcde265 4552c3f6 64e507b9 94b4e092 300165b3 bfc747fe> with parse`

The back4app dashboard shows that the status of the notifications was green. But they were not delivered. I am worried that my users won't get notifications properly because they are not going to uninstall and reinstall...

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell for Back4App's Push Notification for iOS, there are two things that are mainly needed: a valid Certificate and proper Device Tokens.

On your case, since you haven't shared much of how different were your Version A and Version B I'm not really sure if any of those two key info were correct and working.

Also, the green status of the Push might not tell everything, since even if the Push is all set and the status is "SENT", the device might not receive it if it's installation code fails.

My suggestion would be to focus on those two key info, check their [Documentation](https://docs.back4app.com/docs/ios/push-notifications/) and give it a try at their Online Chat Support.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of the difference between version A and B any more, but IIRC, they differed only in version number. I had the same certificate and provisioning profile on both of them. Note that for the second step, I had version B on both of them, and only one phone got notifications. I ended up switching to the ionic platform, so I haven't been able to reproduce recently.